# flash[:notice] messages won't show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making an app that creates and validates some inputs, but I'm having trouble to display error messages through flash[:notice] or success messages, it does validates though

subsidiaries controller

```
class  SubsidiariesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @subsidiaries = Subsidiary.all
  end

  def show
    @subsidiary = Subsidiary.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @subsidiary = Subsidiary.new
  end

  def create
    @subsidiary = Subsidiary.create(subsidiary_params)
    if @subsidiary.save
      redirect_to @subsidiary
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Você deve informar todos os dados'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @subsidiary = Subsidiary.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @subsidiary = Subsidiary.find(params[:id])

    if @subsidiary.update(subsidiary_params)
      redirect_to @subsidiary
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Você deve informar todos os dados'
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def subsidiary_params
    params.require(:subsidiary).permit(:name, :cnpj , :address)
  end
end
```

subsidiaries model

```
class Subsidiary < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :cnpj, :address, presence: true
  validates :cnpj, uniqueness: true, length: {is: 14}, numericality: { only_integer: true}
end
```

subsidiries/new.html

```
<h1><%= @subsidiary.name %></h1><br>
<h1><%= @subsidiary.cnpj %></h1><br>
<h1><%= @subsidiary.address %></h1><br>

<p><%= link_to "Editar", edit_subsidiary_path %></p>
<p><%= link_to "Voltar", subsidiaries_path %></p>
```

Comment: you can use `<h1><%= flash[:alert]</h1>` in your new.html file

Comment: It does not work, because I need it to show only if the object is not saved, If i put it on new.html it will show everytime I register an object, not only when it doesn't save wich is the goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly assign `:notice` message somewhere in the controller, and also somewhere in the view show it. This latter could be in your default view, but it is nowhere present in the code shown.

Comment: just to explain better the problem, I want this message to show, only if the object doesn't save, so if I put on a view it will always show

Comment: I put it on the layout so it only runs when I need it, the problem now is that I need to show different messages for each kind of validation that fails

Comment: Found a better way to implement what I was needing, instead of using flash[:notice], displaying messages with ```<%@object.errors.full_message.each do |message|%>``` on the view simplified and made the code looks better

Comment: Good, but you get only errors with that, right? `:notice` is meant for other things, that's why it is separate from errors and alerts.

Comment: yes that's right, so to explain thoroughly, I was trying to display errors through ```:notice```, but it would only display one standard error, or a weird format if I put ```[:notice] = error.details[some hash]```, for that I did the code above, about the notice, what you said was right, it wasn't present on the view, so I put it on layout since every page can or will use for successfull posts, that also helped me understand what goes where, thank you